# Time.now validation in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just looking for an elegant line that can validate my starts_at field in my table. It just needs to validate that the starts_at field in the form is greater than the current time, cheers.

```
  validates :starts_at, starts_at >= Time.now?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a custom validation for that. Something like:

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :time_is_in_future

  def time_is_in_future
    if starts_at < Time.now
      errors.add(:starts_at, "starts_at must be in the future")
    end
  end
end
```

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

Answer (score 1):

I am using 'validates_timeliness' for effective Time validations instead of hard code.

```
 gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 3.0'
```

Refer here: https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness